# CSS Drop Down List Hover mouse not work

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, mouseover

i have a code HTML CODE:

```
<div class="wrapper-demo">

 <div id="dd" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">Sign in with
                    <ul class="dropdown">
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-twitter icon-large"></i>Twitter</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-github icon-large"></i>Github</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-facebook icon-large"></i>Facebook</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

AND CSS:

```
.wrapper-dropdown-2 {
position: relative; 
width: 200px;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px 15px;

background: #fff;
border-left: 5px solid orange;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: left;
cursor: pointer;
outline: none;

}

.wrapper-dropdown-2:after {
    content: "";
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 16px;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -3px;
    border-width: 6px 6px 0 6px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: grey transparent;

}
.dropdown {
    display:none;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2:hover ul.dropdown  {
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 100%;
    left: -5px;
    right: 0px;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    list-style: none;
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
.wrapper-dropdown-2 .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
    border-left: 5px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pvt3e/

and i try, in hover mouse to: Sign in with open the drop down but its not work !
i cant work with js. Because I have a problem with 1.8.2, but I think we can find a solution with CSS

Comment: `Sign in with` is not a part of menu

Comment: @BindiyaPatoliya can't you see shared fiddle..?

Comment: all code in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pvt3e/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Replace Your This CSS

```
.dropdown:hover  {
  /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    display:block;
    top: 100%;
    left: -5px;
    right: 0px;

    /* Styles */
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    list-style: none;

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

To My CSS and Get Result

```
.wrapper-dropdown-2:hover > .dropdown  {
   position: absolute;
    display:block;
    left: -45px;
       background: white;
      top:24px;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
.wrapper-dropdown-2:hover ul{
    display:block;  
}
```

[updated jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/pvt3e/7/)

also remove .dropdown:hover from your style

Answer (score 1):

You are missing to add hover code to see drop down when hover over. add css for hover.

```
.wrapper-dropdown-2:hover .dropdown
{
    display:block;
}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pvt3e/3/)

Comment: Thanks, but the mouse hover on the DROP DOWN is gone

Answer (score 0):

You will need to initialize your javascript as well as link to jquery. I see you are using a dropdown from Codrops why dont you just download the source?

Comment: i cant work with js. Because I have a problem with 1.8.2, but I think we can find a solution with CSS